# Setting specific table cell value into textbox (jQuery / PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have 1 table with 2 columns. We'll call it col Number and col Letter. It appears as such:

```
1  |  A
2  |  B
3  |  C
4  |  D
```

I have 1 select2 drop down box that has a loop of all the Numbers - and a text box I would like to have the Letter appear that correlates with that number.

HTML/PHP querying current table

```
<label for="number">NUMBER</label>
<select onChange="setLetter(this)" style="text-transform: uppercase;" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="number" id="number">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">-Select-</option>

    <?php
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<option name='".$row["Number"]."' value='".$row["Number"]."'>";
            echo $row["number"];
            echo "</option>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
</select>
</div>
```

JavaScript attempt at querying the value of the select2 box

```
function setLetter(sel)
{
    var col = sel.value;
    <?php
    $number = "SELECT ['Letter'] FROM `msftrail` WHERE ['Number']= '".$col."'";
    ?>
    var php_var = "<?php echo $number; ?>";
    $("#letter").val(php_var);
}
```

How can I populate the Letter text box with the cell in the table that correlates with the correct number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest here would be to put all those rows in an array, and [serializing it as JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Then you can load it up on the client.

HTML+PHP:

```
$msftrail = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<option name='".$row["Number"]."' value='".$row["Number"]."'>";
    echo $row["number"];
    echo "</option>";
    $msftrail[$row['Number']] = $row['Letter']; // Store the mapping from Number to Letter in this array
}
```

JavaScript+PHP:

```
var msftrail = <?php echo json_encode($msftrail); /* Send the array to the client as JSON */ ?>;
function setLetter(sel)
{
    var col = sel.value;
    var php_var = msftrail[col]; // Look up the letter for that number in the array
    $("#letter").val(php_var);
}
```

Comment: Spectacular approach. It works beautifully and is cleanly executed. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could create an Array with all your characters and then call the corresponding character by index.

**Like this:**

```
$foo = array(
             '1' => 'A',
             '2' => 'B',
             '3' => 'C'
);
```

Then you can just get your character by calling your array with the index.

**Like this:**

```
echo $foo['1'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setLetter(sel){
 var tableValue=sel.value
 
 $('.item tr').each(function() {
    var td1 = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html();  
 var td2 = $(this).find("td").eq(1).html();  
 if(tableValue==td1){
   
 $('#out').text(td2);
 }
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="item">
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  
  <td>A</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>B</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>C</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>D</td>
 </tr>

</table>
<form>
 <select onChange="setLetter(this)">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
 </select>
 <br>
 <textarea id="out"></textarea>
</form>
```